# What sort of logs should I see when ignite nodes discovery each other?

Tags: kubernetes, ignite

I'm setting up an ignite cluster in Kuberentes.
Installation is straight forward using this helm chart. [Ignite helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/ignite)
My cluster has network policies enabled, so I added policies for ignite nodes to talk to themselves on all ports. (jdbc, spi_communication, spi_discovery, jmx, sql, rest, thin_clients)

However, my [failover test](https://apache-ignite-binary-protocol-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#failover) clearly shows that they haven't discovered each other to form a cluster.

```
Reconnected to 100.96.0.28:10800
Error: Cache does not exist [cacheId= -479252689]
Reconnected to 100.96.0.28:10800
Error: Cache does not exist [cacheId= -479252689]
```

Also, there's seem to be no logs hinting ignite nodes finding each other.

I'm out of clue atm. So, if anyone has got ignite spi discovery working, could you give an example of what sort of log should I expect?

Answer (score 0):

There is a message that you can see in the logs on each topology change event:

> Topology snapshot [ver=2, locNode=abffa279, servers=2, clients=0,
>   state=ACTIVE, CPUs=32, offheap=32.0GB, heap=16.0GB]

It means that nodes were able to find each other and joined the cluster.

Comment: Thanks. Could you kindly let me know what ports are you using for cluster discovery? Do you use a range?

Comment: Found out why.
We have netpol's enabeld. And it malfunctions when getting messed around too many times.
Having netpol correctly configured to allow ignite nods to talk to 47500 and other ports results in a successful cluster.